I can't get a popup when I click on the custom action button I created with OneDrive & SharPoint FileHandler
I developed a file handler with custom action for my OneDrive and SharePoint environment. I followed the document below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online
I have successfully added my custom button to OneDrive. However, when I click on the button it opens a new tab in the browser. But I want to show a popup instead of a new tab. Normally I thought this could not be done but the application called eshare has done it as can be seen below


As far as I see, we can define our custom URL in the manifest file, but this URL opens a new tab in the browser. My manifest is below:
{
"key":"actions",
"value":"[{\"type\": \"custom\",\"displayName\": \"Test App\",\"url\":\"https://3e6a-159-146-62-18.ngrok-free.app\",\"shortDisplayName\": \"Test App\",\"availableOn\":{ \"file\": {\"extensions\": [\"*\"]},\"folder\": {},\"allowMultiSelect\": true,\"web\":{ }}}]"
}

Is there a way to open it as a popup instead of a new tab?
